# Function to wrap the_content in a div

Tags: functions, the-content

Whenever I've developing a new theme I always wrap `the_content` in a div, like so;

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content();?>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can streamline this process and automatically wrap `the_content` in a div via a function so I don't always have to manually code it and, more importantly, so if my client ever feels like flexing their coding muscles there wont be a problem if they forget to do it...

Answer (score 4):

You can hook `the_content` filter.

paste below code in `functions.php` :

```
<?php
 add_action('the_content','ravs_content_div');
 function ravs_content_div( $content ){
  return '<div class="entry-content">'.$content.'</div>';
 }
?>
```

After paste this code in `functions.php`, `the_content()` print post/page content after wrap content in `div` with class `entry-content`.